# Trying to Login with Selenium but not working

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, recaptcha, webdriverwait

i am playing around with some code for fun. I am trying to login to my mobile carriers website to test out my selenium skills. I get as far as it hitting the login button and it opens up the login window. However, i get stuck here. I believe this is an AJAX login form so i've used the wait function but still doesnt work. Even if i can pass something like 'hello' that would be great.

````
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from secrets import username, password
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Rogers:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/ss/Downloads/geckodriver')

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.rogers.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/browse-root/rci-main/rci-header/section/dsa-header/header[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a/span[2]').click()
        user=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-login/div[1]/form/div[1]/input'))).send_keys('hello')
        pw=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]'))).send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/app-root/div/div/app-login/div[1]/form/div[5]/button').click()

def main():
    R=Rogers(username,password)
    R.login()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i forgot to see that this is an iframe so added in:

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/browse-root/rci-main/div/iframe'))
```